# Error creating Wrapped Component with Typescript and Material-UI ListItem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to convert my React(v16.13.1) app to use Typescript(v3.8.3).
I have a wrapped ListItem (Material-UI v4.9.11) component, that receives a custom prop.

So I'm creating a Prop interface extending ListItemProps, but when I do this, a get an error when using onClick Prop on ListItem component (Error: No overload matches this call.); and another error when using prop Component on my WrappedComponent (MyListItem).

So I tried to include an optional onClick and a component property on the interface. Still, now I get an error on the ListItem Component (Error: No overload matches this call.)

I don't get why the interface interferes with the original ListItem component.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Fragment, FC } from 'react';
import {
  ListItem,
  ListItemProps,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';


interface IListaItem extends ListItemProps {
  to: string;
  component?: React.ElementType;
  onClick?: any;
}

const MyListItem: FC<IListaItem> = ({ to, children, ...props }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleGoTo = () => {
    history.push(to);
  };
  return (
    <ListItem
      selected={location.pathname === to}
      onClick={handleGoTo}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

Here's the complete error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: ReactNode; component?: "symbol" | "object" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | ... 162 more ... | undefined; ... 269 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: ((event: TransitionEvent<...>) => void) | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ button: true; }'.
      Types of property 'button' are incompatible.
        Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'true'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'true'.
```

Comment: what is ListItemProps, do you have the types?

the issue seems related to the property `button` of the `ListItem` component, if you are using a component library they might have a bug

Comment: @DanielPérez Sorry, I forgot to include the imports.
ListItemProps is a type imported of Material-UI. It seems it does a lot of things behind the scenes to create the type dynamically.

Comment: @LeoGouveia resolved? Put here your solution :)